# How to find the order of a group generated by two elements $x$ and $y$ subject only to the relations $x^3 = y^2 = (xy)^2 = 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is the order of a group $G $ generated by two elements $x$ and $y$ subject only to the relations $x^3 = y^2 = (xy)^2 = 1$? List the subgroups of $G$.

Since the above relation is the 'only' relation, I presume that the order of $x$ is $3$ and the order of $y$ is $ 2$. Also y is the inverse of itself, and xy is the inverse of itself. The inverse of $x$ is $x^2$.

I have calculated the elements of the group manually using the given relation. 
$$G = \{1, x, x^2,y, xy, x^2y \}$$

I want to know if there is a formula to calculate the order of $G$? I came across another question where the above relation is $x^3 = y^2 = (xy)^3 = 1$. In this case the group $G has order 12. It is very time consuming to calculate the elements manually. Is there a better way?

Comment: In general, [the problem is undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups), so there is no general formula or algorithm for finding the order of $G$.

Comment: Shorter than calculation sometimes is looking up the given presentation, e.g., [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Dihedral_group).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes! But I am still not good enough in group theory to be able to identify most groups by looking at the presentation :(

Comment: @DRoy You are right, of course. I am also not able to do this. The presentation for $D_3$, however, is easy to identify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we have
$$
xyxy = 1 \implies yx = x^{-1}y^{-1} = x^2y
$$
Since $xy = yx^2$, we conclude that every element of $G$ can be written in the form $x^jy^k$, which means that there are at most $|x| \cdot |y| = 6$ elements.
Listing the elements of $G$, we have:
$$1,x,x^2,y,xy,x^2y$$

---

Elaboration, per request:

Suppose we have a word such as
$x^2 y xy$
we can reduce this with the relation $yx = x^2y$ as
$$
x^2 y^2 xy = \\
x^2 y(yx) y =\\
x^2 y x^2 y y =\\
x^2 (yx) x y^2 =\\
x^2 x^2 (y x) y^2 =\\
x^2 x^2 x^2 y y^2 =\\
x^6 y^3
$$
Perhaps you see how such a method could be extended inductively.

Comment: I came across another question where the above relation is x^3=y^2=(xy)^3=1. In this case the group G has order 12. It is very time consuming to calculate the elements manually. Is there a better way?

Comment: I did not understand how you concluded that every element of G can be written in the form x^j y^k only by looking at the equation xy = yx^2. Can you please explain this part? Thank you.

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: Perhaps you can do something similar using $xyx = yxy$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaboration. Now the idea is perfectly clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

We have $xy=(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$, hence $yxy=x^{-1}$. It is well-known that the group
$\langle x,y \mid x^3=y^2=1, yxy=x^{-1}\rangle $ is the dihedral group $D_3$. It has $6$ elements. Moreover $D_3\simeq C_2\ltimes C_3\simeq S_3$, with $C_2=\langle y \mid y^2=1\rangle$ and $C_3=\langle x \mid x^3=1\rangle$.

Comment: careful: $x^{-1} \neq x$. $G \cong S^3$.

Comment: $x^{-1}\not= x$. $x^{-1}=x^2$

Comment: Yes, thank you. Is $S^3$ not the $3$-sphere ?

Comment: Dihedral group $D_6$ of order $6$ which is isomorphic to $S_3$.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Yes, indeed, but often this is denoted by $D_3$ instead of $D_6$. So $D_n$ has $2n$ elements.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde I prefer to use $D_6$ instead of $D_3$ as I like to keep track of the order of the dihedral group. Hence what you call $D_n$ I would like to call it $D_{2n}$.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Of course, if you prefer this. I just wanted to clarify that your first comment is just the same as in my answer "Moreover $D_3\cong S_3$".